# Regex for currency number, How can I write it shorter?

Tags: regex

```
^((?=.*[1-9]|0)(?:\d{1,3}))((?=.*\d)(?:\.\d{3})?)*((?=.*\d)(?:\,\d\d){1}?){0,1}$
```

I actually think this regular expression is very long, and mayby could be shorter. The problem is i'm not very good with regular expressions and therefore I ask you for help.

Online regex tester http://regexr.com/3a3mk

My rules:

- Starting with 1, 2 or 3 positive numbers [1-9] or 0.
- Adding as many . (followed by 3 numbers [0-9]) as you want.
- Possibility to add a comma with 2 numbers (as decimals)

Positive results

- 0
- 0,55
- 1
- 1,60
- 10
- 10,70
- 100
- 100,80
- 1,10
- 1.000
- 1.000,20
- 10.000
- 10.000,03
- 100.000
- 100.000,08
- 1.000.000.000
- 1.000.000.000,10

Negative results

- 0,0
- 1,1
- 1,000
- 1000.000
- **0.000**
- **0.000,10**
- 1.000,1
- 1.000,100
- 1.0,00
- 1.00,00
- 1.000,0
- **01**
- **012,10**
- **012.123,10**
- **a**
- **a0**
- **0,a**
- **0,aa**
- **1.a00.00**
- **1.000.a1**

[EDIT] Added more negative results

Comment: Side note: this is how any question about regex should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

`^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{3})*)(,[0-9]{2})?$`

matches:

`^` beginning of line

`[1-9]` just one non-zero digit

`[0-9]{0,2}` between 0 and 2 digits

`(\.[0-9]{3})*` zero or more lots of a period and 3 digits

`(0 | [1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{3})*)` either (i) a zero or (ii) up to three digits (the first not a zero) followed by blocks of zero or more lots of a period followed by three digits

`(,[0-9]{2})?` zero or one lots of a comma and 2 digits

`$` end of line

Comment: Doesn't cover his first two positive examples: 0 and 0,55

Comment: Though I notice I am still matching `0.000.10`, which is probably not intended.

Comment: Tweaked again.  Perhaps this time.

Answer (score 8):

The following should suit your needs:

```
^(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2})(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{2})?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/XoNsYoiJ5D-u_Hsy)

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rG3vQ4/2)

Comment: @Mainz007 i missed that check aswell, adding some non digits checks to varify

Comment: Does this also match `0.000,00`?  Should it?

Comment: @Tony: Yes it would and I guess it shouldn't

Comment: Marcel I guess then @Tonys answer now is the best ;)

Comment: @Mainz007 yes it is. But i still like this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You'Re right, that your expression is a bit to long. A shorter version that works with the example numbers and specifications you gave would be this:

```
^(0|\d{1,3})(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})?$
```

**Explanation:**

- `(0|\d{1,3})` checks for a 0 or 1 to 3 digits
- `(\.\d{3})*`checks for a dot and 3 numbers, but because of `*`there can also be none of them
- `(,\d{2})?` ckecks for a comma and two digits, but again it can appear once or not at all.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Your regex is matching `000,55` as well, not sure if that's what the OP is looking for...

Comment: Thanx this does the trick. But if just found a positive result that should be negative (also in my version) 012 / 012,12 is accepted (starting with a 0 is not acceptable) So i go with the answer of @sp00m as he got that covered aswell! Still a thumbs up!